# iPhone Not Sizing My Page Correctly

Tags: iphone, html, ios

So my website sizes correctly on a laptop PC running Windows 7.  Howevever, when run on a iPhone or iPad, a couple things happen.  Here's a link to my site to see www.mazzoreporting.com

First, the video in the right column extends beyond the main content box.   I don't want to change the width because it makes it smaller on laptop pcs.   I believe there is some kind of code I can write in my CSS to fix this?

That's it for now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

you need to make an separate css and load it in case you detect an ipod/iphone/ipad/ other mobile device or better if you can do an excluve mobile version of you page

Answer (score 0):

There is a "secret" HTML incantation that you need to add to the web page to get WebView to resize it.  I *think* that it is:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, user-scalable=yes" />`

(Within the `<head>` section.)